# How to get logged in user id in Magnolia CMS Marketing Tag

Tags: analytics, magnolia

I am looking to setup a custom Marketing Tag in Magnolia CMS, for integrating an Analytics type solution (think MixPanel).

The tool I am looking to integrate collects analytics on a user level, so I need to set the embed code with the currently logged in user id.

I know how to create a custom Marketing Tag and [get it to run some JS](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Marketing+Tags+app#MarketingTagsapp-Testing) (log to the console, for example) but I don't know how to get the currently logged in user id so I could use it in my JS code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
${ctx.user.name}
```

is what you want to insert in your tag code.

Comment: I should probably also add that you would want to exclude pages using such tag from the cache. Magnolia doesn't cache any content created by logged-in users by default, but in case you changed that configuration, you would need to be careful.